# how do i use this linq query to display data using foreach loop in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am not sure how to achieve this. I want to use a foreach loop in my view to display the data in a tabular format. This data will come from a linq query that uses 3-4 tables and selects different fields to display. Not sure how to return this as i get an anonymous type error.

```
var info = from s in context.LennoxSurveyResponses
                       join customers in context.Customers on s.SurveyCode equals customers.SurveyCode
                       join lists in context.CustomerLists on customers.ListId equals lists.ListId
                       join dealer in context.Channels on lists.ChannelId equals dealer.ChannelId
                       where dealer.ChannelId == id
                       select new
                       {
                           ResponseId = s.ResponseId,
                           CustomerFirstName = customers.FirstName,
                           CustomerLastName = customers.LastName,
                           CustomerTestimonial = s.Question5Answer
                       };
```

What would my model have to declare so that can be passed to view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A view works with view models, so start by defining one:

```
public class CustomerViewModel
{
    public int ResponseId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerFirstName { get; set; }
    public string CustomerLastName { get; set; }
    public string CustomerTestimonial { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
public ActionResult Foo(string id)
{
    var info = 
        from s in context.LennoxSurveyResponses
        join customers in context.Customers on s.SurveyCode equals customers.SurveyCode
        join lists in context.CustomerLists on customers.ListId equals lists.ListId
        join dealer in context.Channels on lists.ChannelId equals dealer.ChannelId
        where dealer.ChannelId == id
        select new CustomerViewModel
        {
            ResponseId = s.ResponseId,
            CustomerFirstName = customers.FirstName,
            CustomerLastName = customers.LastName,
            CustomerTestimonial = s.Question5Answer
        };
    return View(info);
}
```

and finally have your view being strongly typed to:

```
@model IEnumerable<CustomerViewModel>
```

now you can <strike>loop</strike> use a display template with this view model to present the information to the user:

```
@Html.DisplayForModel()
```

and inside the corresponding display template (`~/Views/Home/DisplayTemplates/CustomerViewModel.cshtml`):

```
@model CustomerViewModel
<div>
    <span>First name: @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.CustomerFirstName)</span>
    <span>Last name: @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.CustomerLastName)</span>
    ...      
</div>
```

Comment: sorry for the late response..i was out of town and couldn't check your comments until this morning. Thanks!!